# Android Listview's onItemClick issue with custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hey I made a custom viewgroup extends relative layout and override the onTouchEvent():

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            doMyWork();

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            endMywork();

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I also add the onItemClick listener for the listview. But I can't receive:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
```

event in my viewgroup... Could anybody help me?

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: I put this custom viewgroup as my listview's item..

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        doMyWork();

        return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        endMywork();

        break;

    default:
        break;
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and then the listview can't receive the onItemClick event anymore~